# Unable to manage kubernetes from another host via kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

I can't set kubectl on another pc to control a kubernetes cluster.

From the cluster I get the file `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`,
on my local pc I use docker and start the `dtzar/helm-kubectl` image, next i copy the `admin.conf` file.

When I use the command inside the docker container

```
kubectl --kubeconfig /home/admin.conf cluster-info
```

I get a timeout error

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.41.1.100:6443: i/o timeout
```

from the docker image, i can ping and connect via ssh to the server! 
I don't know what to check, to fix it.
Any help is welcome

PS: The cluster ip is in intranet.

Comment: looks like this is the private address `10.41.1.100`. did ping works with the ip? also try to replace with public ip

Comment: Why use `dtzar/helm-kubectl` image and run `kubectl` inside the docker container? Why not install `kubectl` directly on your local PC and run it? Also, make sure that the kubernetes cluster's api-server runs (or is exposed) on the public IP address that your local PC can reach.

Comment: Yes, the ping works and the server, like my pc are on the same intranet. I'm using an docker image, because i need it as last step for set up a CI/CD.

Comment: Please run `ss -lnt | grep 6443` on api-server node and make sure this port is open. By default api-server is listening on port 8443 so maybe try connecting to this port (unless you explicitly changed it to 6443)

Comment: I get `LISTEN   0         128                       *:6443                   *:*`
but i just checked and the company firewall have the port 6443 closed, i have opened a request to IT for that port, and now i have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, the port 6443 was closed in the office firewall, once opened everything started working!